# arrays in PHP multiple choosing from checkboxes

Tags: php

I have an array from checked checkboxes named with numbers which can be true or false
i want to get only then numbers that are 1.

For example:

```
Array ( [8] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] =>  [15] => 1 [16] =>  )
```

i want an array with numbers 8,13,15 because they are 1 in previous array.
Thanks for any help

Comment: where is your code or attempts to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
<?php
$result = array_filter($input, function($var){return $var==1;});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but im wondering now, how to work with the keys now, i just want to simply delete keys as id from database i tried foreach, but i cant get the key value, just the value "1" thanks

Comment: @Zelí I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: `Array
(
    [8] => 1
    [13] => 1
)` i have this array, and i want to delete id 8 and 13 from database with query, but i cant get the values 8 and 13 :(

Comment: @Zelí Use manual, show at least minimal effort. There is ready function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$input  = array(8 => 1, 13 => 1, 14 => null, 15 => 1, 16 => null);
$output = array_filter($input);

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  8 => int 1
  13 => int 1
  15 => int 1
```